# React-table accessor how pass conditionally prop?

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I wonder how I can pass to prop conditionally to my react-table accessor.

eg: I have a data like this:

```
const data = [
  {
    name: 'Something',
    isA: false,
    isB: false,
    isC: true
  },
  {
    name: 'Something 2',
    isA: true,
    isB: false,
    isC: false
  },
  {
    name: 'Something 3',
    isA: false,
    isB: false,
    isC: true
  },
];
```

and my two columns:

```js
const columns = [
  { Header: 'Name', accessor: 'name' }, 
  { Header: 'Is What?', accessor:'?' },  
];
```

Here is in second column accessor how will work like that?
**accessor will be that which one of isA, or isB, or isC true, so if isA true accessor will be isA, if isB accessor will be isB ....**

How to know it?

Comment: React table accessor has another format which takes a function instead of a string..
accessor: data => data.isA || data.isB || data.isC

Comment: i am not 100%sure this will work..but can you try once,

Answer (score 0):

In your `Is What ?` accessor, in order to know which data to show, you can have the accessor like this :

```
{
  Header: "Is What?",
  accessor: a => (a.isA ? "isA" : a.isB ? "isB" : a.isC ? "isC" : "")
}
```

Here, if `isA` is true, you'll see `isA` in your Cell value. However, if `isA` is false and `isB` is true, you'll see `isB` in your Cell value etc.